# Setting title for NSView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, nsstatusitem

I have a `NSStatusItem` in my Cocoa projeсt, targeted on SDK 10.9. I also use `NSStatusItem::setView` here to implement semi-custom tray icon. Obviously, `setTitle` won't work here, because of custom view applied, that's why a question was born. How can I draw a title string for custom `NSView` inside an instance of `NSStatusItem`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.button.title = @"MyTitle";
```

Or… override drawRect in your custom NSView subclass and draw what ever you want to draw.